# Where clause in left join using correlated query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, correlated-subquery

Here's the query:

```
SELECT c.Name As CompanyName, j.ID as JobID, j.Title as JobTitle, 
ja.ApplicationDate, DATEDIFF(MONTH,ja.ApplicationDate, GETDATE()) AS MonthsAgo,
jsc.Name As Recruiter, js.Name As RecruitingAgency, jsh.Name As LastStatus
FROM Companies c
JOIN Jobs j 
ON c.ID = j.CompanyID
JOIN JobApplications ja
ON j.ID = ja.JobID
LEFT JOIN JobContact jsc
ON jsc.ID = j.JobSourceContactID
LEFT JOIN JobContactCompany js
ON jsc.JobSourceCompanyID = js.ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 jh.JobID, jh.StatusDate, jt.Name
    FROM JobStatusHistory jh
    JOIN JobStatusTypes jt
    ON jh.JobStatusTypeID = jt.ID
    --WHERE jh.JobID = j.ID
    ORDER BY jh.StatusDate DESC
    ) jsh
ON j.ID = jsh.JobID
ORDER BY ja.ApplicationDate
```

I'm trying to get the most recent job status for a particular job. I can't figure out how to do the where clause (the commented WHERE) in the LEFT JOIN. I've done this in the past, but can't remember how I did this in the past.

I will be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use OUTER [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx).  A CROSS Apply is like an INNER JOIN where the applied table must return results, whereas an OUTER Apply is like a [LEFT] OUTER JOIN where the applied subquery may return no results.

```
SELECT c.Name As CompanyName, j.ID as JobID, j.Title as JobTitle, 
    ja.ApplicationDate, DATEDIFF(MONTH,ja.ApplicationDate, GETDATE()) AS MonthsAgo,
    jsc.Name As Recruiter, js.Name As RecruitingAgency, jsh.Name As LastStatus
FROM Companies c
JOIN Jobs j ON c.ID = j.CompanyID
JOIN JobApplications ja ON j.ID = ja.JobID
LEFT JOIN JobContact jsc ON jsc.ID = j.JobSourceContactID
LEFT JOIN JobContactCompany js ON jsc.JobSourceCompanyID = js.ID
OUTER APPLY ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 jh.JobID, jh.StatusDate, jt.Name
    FROM JobStatusHistory jh
    JOIN JobStatusTypes jt
    ON jh.JobStatusTypeID = jt.ID
    WHERE jh.JobID = j.ID
    ORDER BY jh.StatusDate DESC
    ) jsh
ORDER BY ja.ApplicationDate
```

Comment: Wasn't aware that there was an APPLY operator. Learned something new today!